# Design refresh in Lotus Domino does not include all design elements

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have one template from which I'm trying to refresh the design in my database.
However when I run "load design -f database.nsf" or select "Refresh design..." in the context menu in the Domino Designer it always skips the same design elements when updating.

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the settings on database level since some elements are updated properly. But I don't know of any other setting on element level than "Prohibit design refresh" that would result in this behavior. If I delete all forms in the database and refresh design again, only those elements that aren't skipped are added to the database.

I have tried creating new copies of database and template, compact, fixup, updall.

Ideas anyone?

**UPDATE 1**

Checked my elements (forms) access settings like Knut Herrman suggested, but this doesn't seem to be the issue either. The settings on the access tab is "All readers and above" and "All authors and above". (Would have posted picture, but sadly I don't have enough reputation)

**UPDATE 2**

Tried deleting all elements in the main database and refreshing after with the result that it skips the same elements as mentioned above.

**UPDATE 3**

I have uploaded a small [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4LsVlEY7tMqVkFJdnQ0VDFyMGM/view?usp=sharing) with a one template and one database, and only two forms for design elements, if someone wants to check it out. One of the forms is updated on Refresh, the other is not.

If I use Replace instead it works fine btw.

Comment: I downloaded your example, and I have duplicated your results. One thing I did notice is that on FormOne (which is the one that does not refresh) the setting for "Who can create documents with this form" on the security tab in the Form Propeties dialog is not "All authors and above". Instead, there are three roles selected. However, I changed this setting - in both the database and the template, and it did not fix the problem. It also still did not work in a new database that I created from the template after changing the form security setting.

Comment: Aah my bad about the security tab settings. Thanks for verifying that though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with a Language setting that was applied to FormOne in your example database. I think the refresh is ignoring elements in the template that it does not think match your current language.

When I looked at the fields tab in the FormOne design properties, I saw an item called $BabelInfo. This item does not exist in FormTwo. My hunch was that this has something to do with Language settings, so I went looking for the Language settings in Domino Designer. I couldn't find them in the regular dialogs and editing panes! But when I looked at both forms in DXL¹ there was a Language property set to EN-gb for FormOne, and there was no Language setting for FormTwo.

Using the DXL editor, I removed the Language setting from FormOne. On first attempt, this had no effect, but then deleted FormOne from the database - which I presumed had inherited the Language setting, though I'm not sure I checked that. I did a refresh and it added FormOne to the database. Then I made another change to FormOne in the template and refreshed again, and FormOne in the database was correctly updated.

¹ I had to search around before I figured out how to get at the form data in DXL. A right click in the forms list in navigation pane brings up "Edit in DXL". That option is not available in the list of forms in the main pane.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your missing design elements need a certain role.

[image]

Define those roles in your destination database's ACL and set the roles for you, your servers and relevant users.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Knut! I updated my question accordingly. In short I don't think this to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be the dates in the main and the template database, that somehow the element in the main db is newer.

Quick solution: delete the element in the main database and refresh it from the template.

Comment: Thanks but already tried that. =/ Will add it to the question.

Comment: What exactly happened when you removed the element and then refreshed the design?

Comment: When I remove one element that refuses to be refreshed and then run Refresh it will simply not be added to the database.

Comment: Could it be that there are multiple elements with the same name in the database? E.g. two forms, or a form and a subform, things like that?

Comment: No it doesn't seem like that is the issue since I managed to replicate the error with only two forms in template and database.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem rather obvious, but double-check that the "Prohibit design refresh or replace to modify" property is not selected in your design element properties, i.e. there should be no ticks in the column highlighted in the image below if you want all elements to refresh.

[image: Capture]

I suspect this may not be the solution, as you said *Replace* is working, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: This was my thought first as well, but it wasn't the problem. None of the design elements that were skipped had that property. Thanks anyway.